# Voice Recognition Software for noting done meetings

Tags: sound, voice-recognition

I am looking for Voice Recognition software that I can have analyze certain audio(s) file(with user(s) voice in it), mark the voice as user(s) x.

The purpose for this is, when in a meeting, the software recognize the voices from its database, mark those voices as users X, Y and Z, and everything what they say will be marked as

- "X: I think we need to have a digital way of noting done our discussions/meetings"
- "Y: Thats seems like good idea."
- "Z: One that recognizes our voices and marks the words as X/Y/Z".

Comment: I don't think we've really gotten to the point where voice recognition can accurately identify a speaker.

Answer (score 0):

For small amount of speakers its enough to have gaussian mixture model classifier. Open source software for speaker identification:

[Alize/Mistral](http://mistral.univ-avignon.fr)

[Kaldi](https://github.com/kaldi-asr/kaldi/tree/master/egs/sre10)

Both are not plug and play, but you can get a reasonably working system.